# Alternative fix to: How can I calculate a Joule thief

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, analysis, joule-thief

This is based on the original question: [How can I calculate a Joule thief](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51936/how-can-i-calculate-a-joule-thief).

Since the gain of common emitter voltage amplifier will depend widely on the
dynamic frequency of the LC unit, either way it's not simple to calculate the output
voltage precisely, I wants to know how could I regulate the output voltage to run my
AVR.

Answer (score 3):

As I have seen Amstrong oscillator circuit configuration in mobil phone chargers, that could be used here too. Simply you could detect overvoltage through a opto-isolator and kill the oscillation and force transistor to cut off.

You only just need a feedback. Study these example. 
[image]

[Original link to circuit,it's public on web](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/05/simple-switched-power-supplies/#.UNXxDG9MkV0)

Please don't do modifications to this circuit , instead get the idea and do 
modifications to your joule theft design.

Hope this will fix your problem. [ Mobil Phone charger idea have been shamelessly
used in everywhere now :P ]